# Double integral in a triangular region

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate:
$\iint_D e^{-y-x} dx\ dy $  where $D$ is the triangle with vertices (0,2), (-3,4) and (4,4).  If someone could guide me through the question I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What are you getting stuck with when you try to solve? Have you sketched your region?

Comment: Hi yes, I've sketched my region. & I have the following lines y=x/2 + 2 and y=-2x/3 + 2 but I think I've calculated the bounds for the integral wrong from here.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have the line y = 4 as well. But I've been watching a video and they didn't show mention the horizontal line of the region

Comment: Hi yes, I've already got this in my sketch. But I'm still not sure how I'm getting this question wrong. I think I might be misunderstanding how to pick the bounds. But I'm pretty sure I have the sketch right so far.

Comment: Let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Hi, yes I finally understand why I had the bounds wrong. I really appreciate your help in helping me understand.

Comment: I am glad it helped. You sketched and already found the equations of lines but that was not in your question. Going forward, you should add those details otherwise people may assume you did not try on your own and may downvote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the equations of the lines are correct.

Here is your region -

[image]

You can integrate over $x$ first going from $(3 - \frac{3}{2}y)$ to $(2y-4)$ between two given lines. Then integrate over $y$ from $2$ to $4$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is
$$\iint_D e^{-y-x} dx\ dy =\int_2^4 \int_{\frac{6-3y}2}^{2y-4} e^{-y-x} dx\ dy =\frac13e^{-8}-\frac73e^{-2}+2e^{-1}
$$